# Is there a better way to optimize my compare_code of two big list of 260k lines in python which works only for a fes rows

Tags: bigdata, complexity-theory

In the company where I work, we are led to compare the names of customers of two files,
it is 11231 lines in the first list and 260897 in the second lists.
I created a program that compiles only on lists of 20 lines.
So I would like some help on my code!

This is for a client relashionship manager.

```
def matching(list_A,list_B):
    D = dict()
    for i in list_A:
        D[i] = dict()
        for j in list_B:
                if levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(i,j,ratio_calc=True) > 0.8:
                    D[i].update({j : levenshtein_ratio_and_distance(i,j,ratio_calc=True)})
    return D
```

I excpect to have a list of all names that look like others with a probability greater than 0.85.

[image]